# Why does Inner join statement show duplicate comments when posting multiple replies

Tags: php, sql-server, join, mysqli, while-loop

I have this comment and reply system -

```
$sql = "SELECT comments.comment_id, comments.user, comments.comment, comments.date, 
comments.post_id, replies.reply, replies.username, replies.replyDate 
    FROM comments 
    LEFT JOIN replies ON comments.comment_id = replies.com_id WHERE comments.post_id=$id";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $date = $row['date'];
    $mydate = date("M jS g:i a",strtotime($date));

    $rdate = $row['replyDate'];
    $newdate = date("M jS g:i a",strtotime($rdate));

    $user = $row['user'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $reply = $row['reply'];
    $comID = $row['comment_id'];
    $post_id= $row['post_id'];

    echo '<div id="comuser">'.$user.': </div>';
    echo '<div id="icomment">'.$comment.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="comdate">'.$mydate.'</div>';
    echo '<div class="replyBTN">reply</div>';
    echo '<form method="post" class="replyForm" action="get_reply.php?reply='.$comID.'&&title='.$title.'&&post='.$post_id.'">';
    echo '<input type="text" id="addReply" name="addReply" placeholder="add reply">';
    echo '</form>';
    echo '<div id="replyCont">';
    echo '<div id="replyUser">'.$username.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="replyDate">'.$newdate.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="reply">'.$reply.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
} else {
echo "<div id='noCom'>no comments..</div>";
}
```

It all works great, I am joining the two tables I have, comments and replies..

But when I leave 2 replies on one comment it duplicates the comment to show both replies instead of posting both replies under the one corresponding comment.. Is my sql statement wrong?

I am joining the 2 tables based on the comment id which is the primary key for comments and inserted into the replies table when a reply is left..

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The Sql is fine, but it WILL produce 2 lines for two replies to one comment.  
To clarify, just run your Sql statement and see what gets returned.  Your code needs to expect multiple Sql rows returned for each comment.  You should group them in the PHP.

Comment: I think replies table has relationship with comments table by 1xN. So, if you have more than one replies tbale register referenced by a comments register. This will duplicate. To make sure, Add some replies table columns to your sql statement and see if they are duplicating as well.

Comment: How do you expect it to return both rows from the `replies` table without also returning the row from the `comments` table with each of them?

Comment: Print the information from the `posts` columns the first time through the loop, and the information from `replies` columns every time.

Comment: @Barmar in the image I posted you can see 2 separate replies but the comment posted twice to display each of them, I am not sure what you mean by print from posts columns?

Comment: I reverted your last edit -- you shouldn't change the code in the question to match the answer, because then future readers can't see what I was fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Every row of the query result contains information from both the `comments` and `replies` table. If you don't want to see the comment information repeated for each reply, just print it on the first iteration of the `while` loop.

```
$first = true;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $date = $row['date'];
    $mydate = date("M jS g:i a",strtotime($date));

    $rdate = $row['replyDate'];
    $newdate = date("M jS g:i a",strtotime($rdate));

    $user = $row['user'];
    $username = $row['username'];
    $comment = $row['comment'];
    $reply = $row['reply'];
    $comID = $row['comment_id'];
    $post_id= $row['post_id'];

    if ($first) {
        echo '<div id="comuser">'.$user.': </div>';
        echo '<div id="icomment">'.$comment.'</div>';
        echo '<div id="comdate">'.$mydate.'</div>';
        echo '<div class="replyBTN">reply</div>';
        echo '<form method="post" class="replyForm" action="get_reply.php?reply='.$comID.'&&title='.$title.'&&post='.$post_id.'">';
        echo '<input type="text" id="addReply" name="addReply" placeholder="add reply">';
        echo '</form>';
        $first = false;
    }
    echo '<div id="replyCont">';
    echo '<div id="replyUser">'.$username.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="replyDate">'.$newdate.'</div>';
    echo '<div id="reply">'.$reply.'</div>';
    echo '</div>';

}
```

BTW, you should use `htmlentities($comment)` and `htmlentities($reply)` to prevent cross-site scripting attacks.

Comment: This definitely fixes the issue I had but creates another, it only prints the first comment not multiple

Comment: I thought there would be only one comment, since the query has `WHERE comments.post_id=$id`. So it would be one comment and all its replies.